# Spring Cloud Contract - Transforming response in Groovy DSL

Tags: rest, groovy, spring-cloud, wiremock, contract

This is my spring contract in groovy file:

```
package com.stubs.contracts

import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

[
        Contract.make {
            description "Stub for my endpoint"
            request {
                method POST()
                url("/rest/v1/value/validate") {
                }
                headers {
                    contentType applicationJson()
                }
                body(
                        file("Request_validate_200.json")
                )
            }
            response {
                body(
                        file("Response_validate_200.json")
                )
                headers {
                    contentType applicationJson()
                }
                status OK()
            }
        }
]
```

My question is:
How to override value for response body?

I want to:
1) load file with request JSON
2) take "id" attribute value from this request
3) replace "id" value property in loaded JSON response

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it out of the box. You could play around with classloaders as we do behind the scenes here (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/blob/master/specs/spring-cloud-contract-spec-java/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/contract/spec/internal/Common.java#L243-L255). In other words, you could create a closure like this:

```
Closure fileLocation = { String relativePath -> 
        URL resource = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                .getResource(relativePath);
        if (resource == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("File [" + relativePath + "] is not present");
        }
        try {
            return new File(resource.toURI());
        }
        catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

call `fileLocation("Response_validate_200.json")` to retrieve the `File`, then convert it to a `String` like this `fileLocation("Response_validate_200.json").text` then use a `JsonSlurper` to parse it `new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(fileLocation("Response_validate_200.json").text)`. From that you'd have to play around with the slurper to modify the contents, and that's pretty much it.